How can I pass Request with bearer/auth using fetch (or axios) api and be able to validate authorization?
I have a page in my Shopify Remix React app using code like the below. My question is how do I add the request headers that Shopify is expecting to authenticate the admin request?
fetch('/api/geocode', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({orders})
}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
  console.log('geocode data', data)
})

On my api.geocode.js I want to validate that they are authorized:
export async function action({request}) {
    const { admin } = await authenticate.admin(request); // does not work  
    const data = await request.json();
}


To authenticate the request to Shopify's Admin API, you'll need to include the appropriate headers, such as the X-Shopify-Access-Token, in your fetch request. These headers will be used on the server side to validate the request. Here’s how you can modify your code to include these headers and authenticate the request on the server side.


  

#Frontend Code
#Update your fetch call to include the necessary headers for authentication:

fetch('/api/geocode', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN', // Replace with your access token
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ orders })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('geocode data', data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
  
  
#Backend Code
#On the server side, you will validate the request by checking the headers. Here’s how you can update the api.geocode.js:

import { authenticate } from './path-to-your-authentication-module';

export async function action({ request }) {
  const authHeader = request.headers.get('X-Shopify-Access-Token');

  // Validate the access token
  if (!authHeader || authHeader !== process.env.SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN) {
    return json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 401 });
  }

  const data = await request.json();

  // Proceed with your logic...

  return json({ success: true, data });
}



Let me know if this helps :D

Thanks, yes it is helpful. So a strange thing I am now able to make fetch requests without adding any headers and the Bearer (JWT) token is automatically being added to my requests, and I can authorize using   import {authenticate} from "../shopify.server.js";  and const { admin } = await authenticate.admin(request);
I tried with and without my X-Shopify-Access-Token adding to the fetch headers like you showed and it works either way. When I decode the Bearer token at https://jwt.io/ it shows the X-Shopify-Access-Token which it calls "aud" inside that token.

The approach of using import { authenticate } from "../shopify.server.js" and const { admin } = await authenticate.admin(request) is correct and ensures that the request is properly authenticated. The presence of the X-Shopify-Access-Token in the aud claim of the decoded JWT token should validate that the request is authorized for admin actions.

You can get token from localstorage if you already login into app
const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); 

After that yo can easily validate if token has header Auth
const authHeader = request.headers.get('Authorization');
  if (!authHeader) {
    return json({ error: 'Authorization header missing' }, { status: 401 });
  }

But if you want to validate if this token valid you can use jsonwebtoken with your secret key
It will be something like this
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);


Your answer is a general answer not really specific to Shopify, shopify needs to authenticate the request like this:
await authenticate.admin(request)
